# Find and set onClickListener on Buttons using a for loop [Android]

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-button

I have created 10 Buttons in the layout file and now I want to "find" them and store them in an Array. Now I want also want to put a different OnClickListener on each of them so that every Button I press does something else. (In my case I want them submit a value from 0-9, so the first button submits 0, the second 1, etc). Here is my code I have so far:

```
package de.lucbe.tilt;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

Button[] buttons = new Button[10];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    for(int i = 0;i < buttons.length; i++ ){
        String buttonID = "button" + i;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
        buttons[i] = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
    }
}
```

}

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i = 0;i<buttons.length;i++){
        Button = buttons[i];
        Button.setId(i);
        Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

in on click the buttons will throw there numbers as id :)

Answer (score 0):

To make things simple you can implement `OnClickListener` into your **MainActivity class** :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
    {

 @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        f1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f1);
        f1.setOnClickListener(this);

        f2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f2);
        f2.setOnClickListener(this);
     }
}
```

Then you have to **Override** the onClick method and switch upon `view.getId()`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.f1:
        // your code here
        break;
    case R.id.f2:
        // your code here 
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for an extra loop.
In your loop itself, after initializing them just put a line: 
buttons[i].setOnClickListener(this);

Implement the OnClickListener ineferfave and then inside the over ridden onClick method just put a switch case for the various ids